# Using template to change behavior of function calls depending on state, in C++

Tags: c++, templates, option-type

I want to do something like this:

I'd like to have a template class similar to boosts "optional", i.e. it should contain a type, and whether the value is valid or not.

Lets say we have a class A with methods

```
A::X(int value) -> int
A::Y(int value) -> int
```

Lets call my template MyOptional

What I'd also like to do is to "interrupt" function calls if the value is not valid. I imagine the return type of all function calls should be 
MyOptional< T >, so for example, doing:

```
MyOptional<A> a;
a->X(3);
```

should give me an Optional without a valid value.

This means I need two pieces of functionality not included in boosts Optional template:

- Conditional function call or template defined behavior depending on state.
- Embedding of return type inside the template type.

Is this even possible in C++? I've been looking at -> overloading, but that seems to determine what object the function call is done with, not allowing me to change the return value itself.

Comment: So you want to `A::X` to return an `Optional` object which has the notion whether the return value(? or input) is valid or not?

Comment: That's not possible directly. I would have a C++11 solution with a different call syntax - you'd do `a.call([](A &p) { p.X(3); });` instead of `a->X(3);`. If that could be useful for you anyway, I will elaborate in an answer.

Comment: Paranaix: Optional< A >::X should return an Optional object, yes, both A and the result of X could be "failed", leading to a invalid Optional so to speak.

Comment: Angew: Unfortunately, C++11 is not available for the project I'm working on, but I'd still be interesting in seeing what you have in mind for future reference :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution using C++11. Suppose `MyOptional` template has the same functionality as `boost::optional` one (such as `operator*`, `operator->`, conversion to `bool` operator etc.). Then we can write function template `Call`:

```
template <class Class, typename Method, typename... Arguments>
auto Call2
    (
        MyOptional<Class>& optional,
        Method Class::*method,
        Arguments&&... arguments
    )
    -> MyOptional
        <decltype((*optional.*method)(std::forward<Arguments>(arguments)...))>
{
    typedef decltype((*optional.*method)(std::forward<Arguments>(arguments)...))
        ResultType;

    if (optional)
    {
        return MyOptional<ResultType>
            ((*optional.*method)(std::forward<Arguments>(arguments)...));
        // you can add here some code for processing the value returned by method
    }
    else
    {
        return MyOptional<ResultType>();
    }
}
```

An example of this function using:

```
MyOptional<A> a;

MyOptional<int> result = Call(a, &A::X, 3);
```

I couldn't find the way to omit `&A::` prefix to method name with language tools only. But there is a way using variadic macro:

```
#define CALL(optional, method, ...) \
    Call(optional, &decltype(optional)::value_type::method, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

It is assumed here that `MyOptional` template defines `value_type` - `typedef` for its argument type.

Example of using:

```
MyOptional<int> result = CALL(ma, X, 3);
```